# Splitting up a large file in BASH using a delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, file

I'm writing a BASH script that takes in a local file, and splits it up into multiple files, using an odd delimiter.

The delimiter I want to use is:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

which separates each record.

Comment: Look at the `csplit` utility.

Answer (score 0):

If your file has its delimiters on their own lines you can do :

```
delim="-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-="
i=1
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == "$delim" ]
    then
        i=$((i+1))
    else
        echo $line >>your_file_$i
    fi
done <your_file
```

If your file isn't in this configuration, it means you have inline delimiters. Therefore you simply have to use `sed "s/${delim}/\r${delim}\r/g"` and you'll be on this case.